# El carousel se ve muy grande

Tags: html, bootstrap, carrusel

Buenas estoy haciendo una pagina web de minecraft y el carousel como que se ve muy grande tengo que hacer scroll para que se puedan ver las letras de abajo y me gustaria que ya nada mas entrar a la web se vea todo el carousel sin necesidad de hacer scroll, no se cual es el problema, seguro que luego es una tonteria pero es que lo he intentado arreglar y no encuentro la solucion si vosotros podeis echarme una mano lo agradeceria.

[image: No se ve el texto hay que bajar]

[image: la imagen no se ve completa tengo que hacer scroll hacia abajo]

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://wallpaperplay.com/walls/full/4/2/2/234831.jpg" alt="First slide">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h5>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam, repellendus.</p>
                  </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://wallpaperplay.com/walls/full/f/8/a/234838.jpg" alt="Second slide">
                 <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h5>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam, repellendus.</p>
                  </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://wallpaperplay.com/walls/full/1/d/4/234836.jpg" alt="Third slide">
                 <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h5>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam, repellendus.</p>
                  </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>

    </div>
```

la css es la de bootstrap.

Web: http://stealand.000webhostapp.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes probar con la clase `vh-100` de `Bootsrtap`, assignandosela a los `items` del `carousel` conseguiras que tengan un tamaño maximo equivalente a la altura de la ventana.

En tu codigo quedaria asi:

```html
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item vh-100 active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://wallpaperplay.com/walls/full/4/2/2/234831.jpg" alt="First slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h5>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam, repellendus.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item vh-100">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://wallpaperplay.com/walls/full/f/8/a/234838.jpg" alt="Second slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h5>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam, repellendus.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item vh-100">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://wallpaperplay.com/walls/full/1/d/4/234836.jpg" alt="Third slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h5>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam, repellendus.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>

</div>
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias era eso 